# How to get all headers from HttpListenerResponse .NET core

Tags: .net, http, proxy, http-headers, httplistener

I have a HttpListenerResponse which Headers array only contains 2 entries. The entire content of the HttpListenerResponse is seen in this picture

[image]

I'm testing my HttpListener by using Postman. In my postman Response I see the following headers: [image]

As you can see the Server and Date headers are present in the response but not in my HttpListenerResponse content. Why are they not there and how can I get them ?

Answer (score 0):

Im not a .Net expert, but when i tried to create an API Gateway i had the same problem. For me, to be able to access all the headers in Net Core, i had to use the interface IHeaderDictionary of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http package. The headers will be a property of HttpContext.Request object.

[image: API Gateway controller that return all headers]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I should've added that I'm restricted to .NET core so unfortunately I can't implement your solution. I'll check and see if the HttpListenerRequest from .NET has a similar option

Comment: No problem. On the official documentation you'll probably find something on similar objects, i think.